# Sentiment Analysis for Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sentiment-analysis, restfb, datumbox

I need to do a Sentiment Analysis for a Facebook page.

I found it on the web a way to do it by using the Graph API and Datumbox API, but it uses the appID and appSecret from the page which the client don't want to share.

I managed to make some extractions from the page by using restFB API instead of facebook4j API, because restFB don't need appID and appSecrect.

Is there a way to do the Sentiment Analysis without the appID and appSecret?

Comment: You can fetch the page's posts and comments without being the page admin. Because normally you see public posts on these pages. So you only need any application id and secret to get everything you need. I don't know Datumbox, but I think you can provide the fetched text snippets from Facebook and get a sentiment analysis.

Comment: I already fetched the page post using the restFB API. I'm just having some difficulties on making the Sentiment Analysis (which I never did before).
After I fetch the data with Hadoop, it is created a file with the page's post data. 
Could you tell me what I should do to make the Sentiment Analysis after the extration?